# Lapply while skipping specific columns R

Tags: r, lapply

Trying to perform a lapply on columns in a dataframe using the below:

```
all <- lapply(all, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Doing this to change the default of the dataframe from chr to numeric, due to defaults when importing from excel.

Is there a way I can do this on all columns except for specific ones? (in this case, skip one column and apply to the rest)  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For skipping a single column you could do something like:

```
all[,-1] <- lapply(all[,-1], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The vector `columns.of.interest` could be either a numeric value representing the columns placement in the data frame or a string consisting of the column names. I used [`sapply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html) to return vectors.

```
# store columns of interest
columns.of.interest <- 2:ncol( all )

# filter by columns of interest
all[ , columns.of.interest ] <- sapply( X = all[ , columns.of.interest ]
                                        , FUN = function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Comment: Your answer was similar to the first answer and is also what I needed.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with `apply`, you can do it this way:

```
col <- c(<specific_columns>)

x[,col] <- apply(x[,col],2,as.numeric)
```

check out the `?apply` in your R console for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify in place with base R :

```
df <- data.frame(a= as.character(1:5),
                 b = as.character(6:10),
                 c = factor(letters[1:5]),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# str(df)
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ a: chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
# $ b: chr  "6" "7" "8" "9" ...
# $ c: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5

df[-3] <- lapply(df[-3], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))

str(df)
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ a: num  1 2 3 4 5
# $ b: num  6 7 8 9 10
# $ c: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
```

Or use library `purrr` and have the same effect using `modify_at` or `modify_if`

```
df2 <- purrr::modify_at(df,.at = c("a","b"),~as.numeric(as.character(.)))
df3 <- purrr::modify_if(df,is.character,~as.numeric(as.character(.)))
```